# Can't Deserialize json property with name "$type"

Tags: c#, json.net

There seems to be a problem with a json property name named "$type".
If I change the name to "$typ" or "$typee" it seems to be working.
At first I thought there is an invisible Unicode character but this doesn't seem to be the case since I copy-paste both the json and the attribute value to [Jon Skeet's Unicode Explorer](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx#explorer) and I can't see anything strange

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

namespace ConsoleAppCompare
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = @"{
                                ""$type"": ""someText"",
                                ""$someName"": ""MoreText"",
                                ""$ThisWorksToo"": ""en"",
                                ""Counting"": true
                            }";

            var movie = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(json);

            Console.WriteLine("Type:"+ movie.type); //type is null here
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class Movie
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$type")]
        public string type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$someName")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$ThisWorksToo")]
        public string Language { get; set; }

        public bool Counting { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an explanation?
I'm using Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3

**Update**
It seems to be working if I move the property somewher else

```
string json = @"{
                 ""$someName"": ""MoreText"",
                 ""$ThisWorksToo"": ""en"",
                  ""$type"": ""someText"",
                  ""Counting"": true
                }";
```

Comment: I have no definitive, but I believe `$type` is a reserved name in newtonsoft, used to store the actual type of the class being serialized. Look here https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm notice how the type's full name is stored in a property called $type.  I don't know how to configure newtonsoft to allow the use of the property name without causing this conflict.

Comment: It is because this property used for serialization of Type of your class.

Comment: heh, what could be possibly wrong...

Comment: yeah, using $ in the begining of variable name is devilish intentions...

Comment: eocron I agree but this is not my json ,I just have to read it. @Will thanks for the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is reserved name in Newtonsoft.Json and used for serialization of Type representing the class. It is enabled for serialization/deserialization by specifying JsonSerializerSettings:

```
new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
}
```

Comment: When you use `TypeNameHandling.None` does it allow for use of `"$type"` in json property names?

Comment: @Will No ,it doesn't

Answer (score 4):

you should use JsonSerializerSettings.
Deserialize your json string with blow code :

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
      MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
      DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None
};

var movie = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(json,settings);
```

Comment: @nick This should be the accepted answer, it works exactly as described.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer and should be accepted.